# Assigning matrices with one for loop using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

Assume there is a matrix, arr[10][10]. I want to be able to assign values to every element in only one for loop. All the solutions I've seen (even the ones using pointers) have 2 for loops.

Comment: Assuming you are using C, have you tried `memset` or `memcpy`? (Really unclear what you actually want to assign, though)

Comment: I'm using C++. What do you mean, unclear? I want to assign integers to a matrix.

Comment: Why use a 2D array if you want to only use 1 for loop? It's simple enough, using `%` and `/` to calculate each index, but I'm not sure why you would want to …

Comment: Maybe provide a [mre] of what you are currently doing. Also, what makes you think that using two nested loops is bad? (Just one loop can be more efficient -- at the cost readability -- but that really depends on what you are doing)

Comment: @ChrisMM it's an assignment. I don't get it, what do you mean "calculate"? Calculate what?

Comment: @chtz It's an assignment so I have to use one for loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are really many possibilities. They rely on contiguous allocation of memory for an array.

So, I would not recommend any of them. Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 10U;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 10U;
constexpr size_t NumberOfCells = NumberOfRows * NumberOfColumns;

int main() {

    // Definition of our array
    int data[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

    // Lambda to print the array on the screen
    auto print = [](int(&array2Dim)[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns]) { std::cout << "\n\n"; for (size_t r = 0U; r < NumberOfRows; ++r) {
        for (size_t c = 0U; c < NumberOfColumns; ++c) std::cout << array2Dim[r][c] << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    }};

    // One possible solution
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCells; i++) {
        *((*data)+i) = i;
    }
    print(data);

    // Other possible solution
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCells; i++) {
        data[0][i]= i*2;
    }
    print(data);

    // 3rd solution: No loop
    std::iota(*data, *data + NumberOfCells, 500);
    print(data);

    return 0;
}
```

By the way. You should not use plain C-Style arrays in C++. You should not use raw pointers for owned memory.